# Comparación de dos arreglos

Tags: php, html, array

Codigó:

```html
<?php

$arreglo1=array
(
array("Daniel Paz", "Cra. 45 # 45-56","565-694-2210","13/04/1998", "Blanco"),
array("Yael Díaz","875 Langosh Ranch","556-179-2035","14/06/2002","Rojo"),
array("Ada Peréz","Clle. 23 # 12-19 Sur","472-829-806","23/12/1997", "Naranja"),
array("Alex Ortiz","Av. 34 # 16-12","(603) 387-1630","12/10/1980", "Amarillo"),
array("Luz Yepes","5423 Zieme Underpass","1-219-744-1485","30/11/1990", "Azul")
);

$arreglo2=array
(
    "Rojo"=>"Persona enérgica y vitalista", 
    "Naranja"=>"Persona divertida y sensual",
    "Amarillo"=>"Persona inquisitiva y curiosa",
    "Azul"=>"Persona comunicativa",
);

$tabla="<table width='60%' align='center'>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Nombre</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Dirección</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Teléfono</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Fecha de cumpleaños</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Color favorito</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Significado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="php.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Ejercicio 2</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

foreach ($arreglo1 as $datos) {
    $tabla.="
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>$datos[0]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[1]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[2]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[3]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[4]</td>";

    $significado="";

    foreach ($arreglo2 as $nombre_color => $valor) {
        if ($datos[4]==$nombre_color) {
            $significado=$valor;
        }
            if ($significado=="") {
            $signficado="No se encuentra el significado";
        }
    }
    $tabla.="
        <td align='center'>$significado</td>
    </tr>";
}

echo $tabla;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Buenas mi problema es el siguiente:

- En el registro de cada persona del listado, es preciso que el sistema evalúe
  si el nombre del color existe en un segundo arreglo que contiene: el nombre
  del color y el significado de cada uno, en caso de encontrarlo, es necesario
  escribir en una última columna de la Tabla 1 el significado del color, de lo
  contrario debe escribir la frase "No se encuentra el significado".

Lo que pasa es que cuando no se encuentra el color de esa persona no devuelve el mensaje "No se encuentra el significado" y no se porque. Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Dentro del segundo if la variable significado está mal escrita, por eso no sale, falta una i

Comment: Hay que tonto soy Dioos, muchas gracias :D, eso pasa por usar el autocompletado xD

Comment: Cosas que pasan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel, no tienes necesidad de recorrer **caaada vez `$arreglo2` para buscar si el valor está**. Si ya tienes la clave, puedes verificar si está por esa clave directamente usando `isset`. Y puedes usar un operador ternario para asignar a `$significado` sea el valor del array, sea el valor `"No se encuentra el significado"`.

O sea, puedes cambiar **todo** esto:

```
$significado="";

foreach ($arreglo2 as $nombre_color => $valor) {
    if ($datos[4]==$nombre_color) {
        $significado=$valor;
    }
        if ($significado=="") {
        $signficado="No se encuentra el significado";
    }
}
```

Por **sencillamente** esto:

```
    $significado=(isset ($arreglo2[$datos[4]])) ? $arreglo2[$datos[4]] : "No se encuentra el significado";
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
<?php

$arreglo1=array
(
array("Daniel Paz", "Cra. 45 # 45-56","565-694-2210","13/04/1998", "Blanco"),
array("Yael Díaz","875 Langosh Ranch","556-179-2035","14/06/2002","Rojo"),
array("Ada Peréz","Clle. 23 # 12-19 Sur","472-829-806","23/12/1997", "Naranja"),
array("Alex Ortiz","Av. 34 # 16-12","(603) 387-1630","12/10/1980", "Amarillo"),
array("Luz Yepes","5423 Zieme Underpass","1-219-744-1485","30/11/1990", "Azul")
);

$arreglo2=array
(
    "Rojo"=>"Persona enérgica y vitalista", 
    "Naranja"=>"Persona divertida y sensual",
    "Amarillo"=>"Persona inquisitiva y curiosa",
    "Azul"=>"Persona comunicativa",
);

$tabla="<table width='60%' align='center'>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Nombre</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Dirección</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Teléfono</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Fecha de cumpleaños</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Color favorito</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Significado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";


foreach ($arreglo1 as $datos) {
    $tabla.="
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>$datos[0]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[1]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[2]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[3]</td>
        <td align='center'>$datos[4]</td>";

        $significado=(isset ($arreglo2[$datos[4]])) ? $arreglo2[$datos[4]] : "No se encuentra el significado";

    $tabla.="
        <td align='center'>$significado</td>
    </tr>";
}
$tabla.="</tbody></table>";
echo $tabla;

?>
```

Por cierto, te faltaba cerrar el `tbody` y `table`...

**Salida:**

```html
<table width='60%' align='center'>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Nombre</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Dirección</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Teléfono</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Fecha de cumpleaños</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Color favorito</th>
        <th bgcolor='#0080C0'>Significado</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Daniel Paz</td>
        <td align='center'>Cra. 45 # 45-56</td>
        <td align='center'>565-694-2210</td>
        <td align='center'>13/04/1998</td>
        <td align='center'>Blanco</td>
        <td align='center'>No se encuentra el significado</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Yael Díaz</td>
        <td align='center'>875 Langosh Ranch</td>
        <td align='center'>556-179-2035</td>
        <td align='center'>14/06/2002</td>
        <td align='center'>Rojo</td>
        <td align='center'>Persona enérgica y vitalista</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Ada Peréz</td>
        <td align='center'>Clle. 23 # 12-19 Sur</td>
        <td align='center'>472-829-806</td>
        <td align='center'>23/12/1997</td>
        <td align='center'>Naranja</td>
        <td align='center'>Persona divertida y sensual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Alex Ortiz</td>
        <td align='center'>Av. 34 # 16-12</td>
        <td align='center'>(603) 387-1630</td>
        <td align='center'>12/10/1980</td>
        <td align='center'>Amarillo</td>
        <td align='center'>Persona inquisitiva y curiosa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>Luz Yepes</td>
        <td align='center'>5423 Zieme Underpass</td>
        <td align='center'>1-219-744-1485</td>
        <td align='center'>30/11/1990</td>
        <td align='center'>Azul</td>
        <td align='center'>Persona comunicativa</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, tienes mucha razón no me acordaba del operador ternario y lo de la el tbody y el table al revisar el código ayer lo corregí, Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

Eyy a mi tambien me colocaron ese mismo trabajo muchisimas gracias lo unico que hice de mas fue q le inserte codigo html y desde alli defini las propiedades del texto y de la tabla para no repetirlo mas durante el proceso.